# How to sort the main list based on inner list data in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, java-stream, comparator

I have to sort the main object based on the data of the inner list. I have classes like below

```
class Organization{
    private List<Department> departments;
}

class Department{
    List<Subject> subjects;
    List<Employee> employees;
}
class Subject{
    String subjectCode;
    String subjectName;
}
class Employee {
    String employeeId;
    String employeeName;
}
```

`Subject` was declared as `List` but it will have a single object in it. I need first to sort the `Departments` data based on `subjectCode` and then `employeeName`.

Here is my sample input

```
{
  "departments": [
    {
      "subjects": [
        {
          "subjectCode": "100",
          "subjectName": "Chemistry"
        }
      ],
      "employees": [
        {
          "employeeId": "emp_1",
          "employeeName": "Ben"
        },
        {
          "employeeId": "emp_5",
          "employeeName": "Tom"
        },
        {
          "employeeId": "emp_3",
          "employeeName": "Henry"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subjects": [
        {
          "subjectCode": "102",
          "subjectName": "Physics"
        }
      ],
      "employees": [
        {
          "employeeId": "emp_4",
          "employeeName": "Chris"
        },
        {
          "employeeId": "emp_5",
          "employeeName": "Tom"
        },
        {
          "employeeId": "emp_6",
          "employeeName": "Jim"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and the expected output is

[image]

Is it possible to sort using java8 features in a single line or do I need to write multiple custom Comparators to group the employees under same `subjectCode`.

Comment: Please share your attempt, and describe the problem you've faced (like Exception, compilation Error). If your code compiles and running, then post the output which it produces.

Comment: Have you looked into comparable/comparator?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I'm able to sort the employees using below logic `organization.getDepartments().forEach(department -> {
   department.getEmployees().sort(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getEmployeeName)));
  }); `. Now how can I sort the departments based on subject code `organization.getDepartments().sort(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Department::?????)))`;

Comment: @user2692291 Please [*add this code into the question*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73099612/edit) so that everyone can see it.

Comment: Your sorting criteria is unclear `sort the Departments data based on subjectCode and then employeeName`. Department can contain multiple subjects and many employees - that means no single `subjectCode` and `employeeName` we can rely on. In your example there's only **one** subject subject in the list, does implies that you want to use the code of the first subject? The same applies for employee.

Comment: I think you want `Comparator.comparingInt(dep -> Integer.parseInt(dep.getSubjects().get(0)))`.

Comment: If subject codes are unique - there's no need to entail employees. Have a look at the comparator posted by [*OleV.V.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099612/how-to-sort-the-main-list-based-on-inner-list-data-in-java?noredirect=1#comment129106732_73099612)

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko yes, I wanted to use code of the first subject to sort the departments. But employees data has to be sorted internally which I was able to do per previous comment, I don't need to sort the departments based on the employees data.

Comment: `employees data has to be sorted internally` - just apply these two sorting operations separately, since they don't interfere anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution based on above comments from @Alex and @Ole

```
organization.getDepartments().forEach(department -> {
            department.getEmployees().sort(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getEmployeeName)));
        });
organization.getDepartments().sort(Comparator.comparingInt(department -> Integer.parseInt(department.getSubjects().get(0).getSubjectCode())));
```